# DFRobot pH sensor v2 calibration using push button

Tags: arduino

I have tested SEN0161-V2 and I can calibrate it via serial monitor. The library that I use is the one from DFRobot. Then, if I wanna do a calibration via push button, should I change the library or any other things I need to do?